# Reuse subquery results for other computations with SQL Server

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a set of queries like this one in Access that run fine, but when I try to make them either a view or stored procedure in MS SQL, it tells me that the subquery's alias is not a valid column to use later in the query to run a calculation on.

Here's what I have in Access:

```
SELECT T.DistrictNum,

(select count(winner) from TournyGames2013 where type='Pool 1' and winner=T.DistrictNum) AS TeamWins, 
(select count(loser) from TournyGames2013 where type='Pool 1' and loser=T.DistrictNum) AS TeamLoses,
([TeamWins]+[TeamLoses]) AS GameTotal
FROM TournyTeams2013 AS T
WHERE T.Pool=1
```

How in the world do I make a view or stored procedure from this that works?
Thanks, be gentle, my first post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server (as with other databases that adhere to the ANSI standard), you cannot reference an alias at the same level of `select` where it is defined.

You can easily fix this using a subquery:

```
select t.*, ([TeamWins]+[TeamLoses]) AS GameTotal
from (SELECT T.DistrictNum,
             (select count(winner) from TournyGames2013 where type='Pool 1' and winner=T.DistrictNum) AS TeamWins, 
             (select count(loser) from TournyGames2013 where type='Pool 1' and loser=T.DistrictNum) AS TeamLoses
      FROM TournyTeams2013 AS T
      WHERE T.Pool=1
     ) t
```